# carregar um formulario específico de acordo com o botão radio selecionado

Tags: jquery, html

supondo que eu tenha duas opções no começo de um formulário, a opção A e a opção B

```
<label>SELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO</label>
<form>
  <label><input value="A" name="opcao" type="radio">opcao A</label> 
  <label><input value="B" name="opcao" type="radio">opcao B</label> 
</form>
```

Supondo que eu selecione a opção A, eu quero que carregue o formulário A, em tese o formulario A seria tipo assim:

```
<form id="A">
  <input name="A" placeholder="A opção "A" do botão radio foi selecionada"
</form>
```

E consequentemente se eu selecionar a opção B, o formulário referente ao B será carregado:

```
<form id="B">
  <input name="B" placeholder="A opção "B" do botão radio foi selecionada"
</form>
```

Comment: O que acontece que faz passar de `<form>` para `<form A>` ou `<form B>`?

Comment: Tu quer que ao dar um :checked no input A o form #A apareça e o mesmo no #B?

Comment: Isso ai mesmo @haykou

Comment: Perdão @brasofilo, mas não entendi seu cometário.

Comment: Mal entendido meu, por favor, descartar comentário anterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais simples de se realizar esse procedimento seria assim:

**HTML**

```
<label>SELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO</label>
<form id='form-id'>
    <label><input id='form1' value="A" name="opcao" type="radio">opcao A</input></label> 
  <label><input id='form2' value="B" name="opcao" type="radio">opcao B</input></label> 
</form>
<form id="A" style="display:none;">
    <input name="A" placeholder="A opção A do botão radio foi selecionada"></input>
</form>
<form id="B" style="display:none;">
  <input name="B" placeholder="A opção B do botão radio foi selecionada"></input>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#form-id').change(function() {
    if ($('#form1').prop('checked')) {
        $('#A').show();
        $('#B').hide();
    } else {
        $('#B').show();
        $('#A').hide();
    }
});
```

Sendo assim, conforme você realiza uma mudança no Button Radio, o JS vai verificar se o primeiro esta "Checked", caso sim, ele mostra o primeiro e some com o segundo, se não for o primeiro, ele vai fazer o mesmo com o segundo Radio, só que invertendo quem mostra.

Se necessário adicionar mais formulários, você pode especificar em algum outro IF, ou se não, pode capturar os elementos por Classe, verificar qual foi selecionado, e retornar o ID para saber qual formulário deve ser exposto.

Exemplo Prático: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/marceloavf/9XXRY/63/)

Comment: Simples e prático! Muito Bom!

Answer (score 1):

Crie um arquivo para cada *form*, e faça um load do selecionado:

**index.html**

```
<button class="carregaform" data-form="A">Formulário A</button>
<button class="carregaform" data-form="B">Formulário B</button>

<div id="formulario">

</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.carregaform').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     form = ($(this).attr('data-form') == 'A' ? 'form-A.html' : 'form-B.html');
     $('#formulario').load(form);
   });
});
</script>
```

**form-A.html**

```
<form id="A">
  <input name="A" placeholder="A opção 'A' do botão radio foi selecionada">
</form>
```

**form-B.html**

```
<form id="B">
  <input name="B" placeholder="A opção 'B' do botão radio foi selecionada">
</form>
```